# Path is correct when printed to console, but not in pandas .to_csv method

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib

Here's a frustrating one that I don't understand:

```
from pathlib import Path
DATA_DIR = "c:/my/dir/"
[...]
df.to_csv(Path(DATA_DIR).parent.joinpath(DATA_DIR, "c_bat.csv"))
```

This gives an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\my\\dir\\c_bat.csv'
```

However, when I do this:

```
print(Path(DATA_DIR).parent.joinpath(DATA_DIR, "c_bat.csv"))
```

It prints fine:

C:\my\dir\c_bat.csv

Why does Print get it right, but df.to_csv get it so wrong, when it's ostensibly the exact same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most practical way to deal with joining paths using pathlib is the "slash"
operator, as in the following code:

```
# Common name used in pathlib examples
p = Path(DATA_DIR)
[...]
df.to_csv(p / "c_bat.csv"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me:

data.to_csv(DATA_DIR / "c_bat.csv")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Jason: please note that the slash operator is used on the variable `p`, which is class Path. In your comment, you use DATA_DIR, which is of type str.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I get it! Thanks! It works great now. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Excellent. If you like the answer, please accept it as the answer.